# How to restore object repository after adding a new project type when getting "Invalid image size" error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I was playing around with adding a new project type to the object repository. I've added an icon and a description, but nothing else and now I can no longer do a File|New|Other, which really makes working with Delphi difficult.

I can get to the Customize menu (File|New|Customize) and I can see what I "added" and the icon is there with its description:

[image]

But when I try to go to File|New|Other, I get the **Invalid image size** error:

[image]

and I can't seem to figure out how to undo what I did. Clicking on **Details** button yields the following:

```
[5056DAB9]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.ImgList.TCustomImageList.CheckImage (Line 1021, "Vcl.ImgList.pas" + 4) + $1C
[5056CA1A]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.ImgList.TCustomImageList.AddIcon (Line 553, "Vcl.ImgList.pas" + 5) + $4
[20633A5E]{coreide190.bpl} GalBrow.AddIcons (Line 295, "GalBrow.pas" + 47) + $1
[2063539F]{coreide190.bpl} GalBrow.TGalleryBrowseDlg.LoadGallery (Line 982, "GalBrow.pas" + 34) + $1D
[20633B68]{coreide190.bpl} GalBrow.BrowseNewDialog (Line 326, "GalBrow.pas" + 6) + $A
[20633B16]{coreide190.bpl} GalBrow.AddIcons (Line 303, "GalBrow.pas" + 55) + $91
[2063882C]{coreide190.bpl} Gallery.LoadGallery (Line 721, "Gallery.pas" + 33) + $36
[0041FB6F]{bds.exe     } AppMain.{System.Generics.Collections}TList<IDEDesktopComboBox.TDesktopComboBox>.Expand (Line 1061, "System.Generics.Collections.pas" + 1) + $0
[50173CB3]{rtl190.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicAction.Execute (Line 16505, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $6
[5044C27F]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.ActnList.TCustomAction.Execute (Line 284, "Vcl.ActnList.pas" + 19) + $35
[50173B53]{rtl190.bpl  } System.Classes.TBasicActionLink.Execute (Line 16422, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $7
[218550F1]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.ExecAction (Line 1077, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 6) + $D
[2185699C]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 1843, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 19) + $15
[2185A3BA]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMainMenuBar.TrackMenu (Line 3637, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 5) + $3
[21854CE8]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.CMItemKeyed (Line 989, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 2) + $11
[21854CF1]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.CMItemKeyed (Line 990, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 3) + $4
[50462B49]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7224, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[505876F5]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc (Line 4388, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 201) + $5
[5005FB14]{rtl190.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 17402, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5005F694]{rtl190.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 17095, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[51F18607]{vcldesigner190.bpl} VCLFormContainer.TControlSizer.ControlWndProc (Line 313, "VCLFormContainer.pas" + 33) + $C
[5005F518]{rtl190.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 17013, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[5005F822]{rtl190.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17199, "System.pas" + 1) + $2
[5005F873]{rtl190.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 17221, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[50444B5B]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7047, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) + $8
[50466CAC]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9751, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[50466CC1]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9754, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $0
[501749C4]{rtl190.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 17010, "System.Classes.pas" + 5) + $0
[50467669]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10039, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 153) + $6
[16165C51]{cxLibraryRS19.bpl} Dxhooks. + $0
[21856AB2]{vclactnband190.bpl} Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.WndProc (Line 1882, "Vcl.ActnMenus.pas" + 25) + $4
[50466CAC]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9751, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[501749C4]{rtl190.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 17010, "System.Classes.pas" + 5) + $0
[5045D8FA]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.FindControl (Line 3559, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $9
[50590DC3]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10288, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[50590E06]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10318, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[50591141]{vcl190.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10456, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Comment: Not sure if it is of any help, but this error message clearly belongs `TCustomImageList.AddIcon`. I'd examine offending repository icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways roll this back:

1) delete the RADStudioRepository.xml file that resides in \AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\12.0.  Delphi recreates a default file when restarted

2) edit the RADStudioRepository.xml file to remove the offending entries.